# EmberJS: how to POST, then edit immediately

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to do the following:

- "create" an object (via POST to the server)
- then immediately edit it on the client.

So basically it means the UI could just stay the same - except the next time "submit" is clicked, the form is PUT instead of POSTed.

1- Right now, as soon as I submit the form, it is refreshed with new data.

Why does it do this?

```
    App.FooNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      ...
      events: {
        submit: function(){ 
            this.store.commit(); // The form content changes
        }
      }

    });
```

2- My first, blunt approach to do POST then Edit was to call

```
    this.transitionTo('foo.edit', this.get('controller').get('model'));
```

right after

```
    this.store.commit();
```

but it won't work, and I understand why (the object is still "being saved" - or inFlight -) when I try to edit it.

But how can it be done?

Thanks!
PJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you'll need to wait for transaction to complete before transitioning.

```
App.FooNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  ...

  events: {
    submit: function(){
      var foo,
        _this = this;
      foo = this.get('controller').get('model'); 

      // Register a one-time callback for the 'didCreate' event
      foo.one('didCreate', function() {
        // At this point the model's id has not been set, so wait till next run loop
        Ember.run.next(_this, function() {
          // Now foo is ready, transition to edit
          this.transitionTo("foo.edit", foo);
        });
      });
      this.store.commit();
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael. It works great! Just one thing: what is this "setTags()" on the controller? I can't find it in my version of Ember. Does it come from another part of your app?

Comment: Doh! Good catch, that was from another part of our app.