# Hitting refresh button after call to createRecord causes EmberData to send erroneous GET message

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I posted this on the Ember-Data issues list:

https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1796

I read some posting saying that an 'id' should not be specified during call to createRecord.  I tried this and noticed the following: if an 'id' is not specified, hitting the refresh button will cause Ember Data to send a GET request to the server requesting a record with a 'null' id, so it doesn't solve the problem.

Does anyone have a suggestion on a workaround for this?

I've also posted a somewhat related problem here (rogue GET message):
https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1794

Answer (score 0):

That's not really a bug, you're just note really programming asynchronously. You have your `transitionTo` call *before* the record is done being created. So you're routing to a page that does not yet exist. While Ember.js might have some fancy features to make that not an issue, it can't handle every scenario. What you should be doing it routing *after* the record is created. Since `createRecord` returns a record and not a promise, I suggest using the `didCreate` hook.

```
var newRec = this.store.createRecord('scenario', temp);
newRecord.one('didCreate', function() {
    Em.run.next(function() {
        this.transitionToRoute ('scenarios.scenario', newRec);
    }.bind(this));
}.bind(this));
```

You can see another similar example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096289/emberjs-how-to-post-then-edit-immediately).

Comment: I tried adding your code snippet to the JSBIN, but the event never fires for some reason.  Can you edit the JSBIN and see if you're seeing the same thing?

I'm actually a bit confused by this.  If I transitioned to the route without waiting for the didCreate event, things seem to work because I can see the sName property being displayed.  It's hitting the refresh button that caused the GET message to be sent.  One would think in a tiny program such as this example, the record would have been created by the time I hit the refresh button.

Comment: Since I can't get the event to fire, I tried placing the transitionToRoute inside 'if (newRec.get('isLoaded'))' to ensure I don't transition unless the record has been created already.  After transitioning, hitting refresh still sends the GET message.  Given this behavior, I still think this is a bug - do you agree?

Comment: It says in the API [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_isLoaded) that `isLoaded` is true directly after creating the record, even before it's saved.

Comment: Good point, I remember reading that.  But I should be able to transition to the route as long as it's loaded, and before record is saved to the server - right?  Can you get the event to fire?

Comment: I waited 15 seconds before hitting the refresh button, and the GET still gets send.  Something's not right.

Comment: I'll try getting your event to fire, but the GET request really has nothing to do with this. The GET request is failing because your URL is bad. You transition to a URL with a dynamic segment in which the route is null. Your URL is `#/scenario/null`, so when the refresh happens, Ember tries to resolve the scenario with ID `null`. If you don't transition to a bad URL, that request will never fire.

Comment: Your JSBin doesn't load. I can't even get the button to show.

Comment: I'm seeing /scenario/1 on the server and Ember inspector, which is what I expected since I gave the record an id=1 during call to createRecord.  Server comes back with notFound because record was never saved to the server.  But as long as record is loaded, it should be in the store and Ember shouldn't have to ask for same record from the server.

Comment: Yea, for some reason, I can never seem to get JSBIN to work.  Example is really simple, any idea as to why it's not working in JSBIN?  I can run the same code on my computer fine.

Comment: How did you give the record an ID of 1? Only the server (or possibly your adapter) is supposed to do that. Either way, it would make since that the store tries to fetch an unsaved record. If it hasn't been persisted to the server, it technically doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I assign the id during call to createRecord (see sample code in JSBIN).  Some people prefer not to do that, but according to everything I've read, it's perfectly valid.  In my case, it's more convenient.  I think Ember's fine with that because it used that id in the GET message.  I don't agree that the record technically doesn't exist until persisted to server.  The record exists if it's loaded, which means either created locally or obtained from the server.  Still don't know why the didCreate event doesn't fire though.

Comment: Some people prefer not to do it because you're not supposed to do it. The adapter has a hook for that: use it. Relying on undefined behavior when there's built in support is just silly. Also, the `didCreate` event won't fire if the record errors somehow (for instance, if Ember tries to assign an ID to a record that already has one). I can't get your code to run, but I'm sure there are exceptions logged in the console.

Comment: I tried creating the record without the id.  The event still doesn't fire, and there's no error on the console.  Where's the hook in the adapter?  RestAdapter?

Comment: I implemented the generateIdForRecord hook as you suggested, and verified that an id was being generated.  The didCreate event still didn't fire.